# How to name an Android application package for a site that does not begin with ".com"

Tags: java, android, package

I have been using this beginner's tutorial (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project) on Android application development to help me create my first Android application.

For the "Configure your project" window, the tutorial suggests using "com.example.myfirstapp" as a package name. (Obviously, my real app would not be called "myfirstapp": this is just an example.)

However, I already own a website with a subdomain and a domain other than ".com".  I was actually hoping to use a website with a URL like "https://myfirstapp.github.io/" (GitHub Pages).

For my Android application, should I name the package: "io.github.myfirstapp"? Or should it be "io.github.myfirstapp.myfirstapp" since the first "myfirstapp" is part of the website name? Or should it not be that at all, since I don't own "GitHub"... I'm a little confused.

Comment: This is opinion based. You can have any package name (as long as it's not taken on google play if you plan to publish it). For all Java/Android cares is that you have a package name. Even `cat.dog.meow` would be valid.

Comment: Oh. I thought there was a specific naming convention and that I would start experiencing problems if I differed from the .com convention.

Comment: Nope. It can be any valid name in structure x.x.x.....

Comment: The primary objective is uniqueness. The secondary objective is to avoid getting sued. From a uniqueness standpoint, `io.github.myfirstapp` would work. But GitHub is a trademark owned by Microsoft. Personally, I would not use it in an application ID.

Comment: It is a convention, but it's only a convention. Deviating won't cause you problems.  Any package name is fine, including ones based on domain names with non-.com TLDs. And yes, your understanding is correct. "io.github.myfirstapp.myfirstapp" would follow the convention properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments posted above, it is okay to use a domain other than ".com" in the package name. ".io" and ".org" work as well. However, try to avoid using copyrighted or trademarked names to avoid any legal consequences.

Answer (score 2):

The package name is used for unique for your application.
Android uses the package name to determine if the application has been installed or not.
The general naming conventions can be like:

> com.organizationname.applicationname

eg:

com.facebook.katana (Facebook app)

Or

> com.orgnizationname

eg: 
com.whatsapp (Whatsapp messenger)

Answer (score 1):

a best practice for defining a package name is to use a reverse domain like you just mentioned : `com.android.example`. If you have a different top-level-domain it is also ok.

As a company you could use somethin like `com.companyname.appname` or even use another subdomain like `com.companyname.customername.appname`